# How do I specify that "NOW()" refer to a 24-hour clock in a mysql query (as opposed to 12 hour)?

Tags: mysql, insert

Currently, my code to insert into the database is as follows:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO lookup_table (
    the_date
        )
VALUES(
        NOW()
)
";)
```

In one line, that's:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO lookup_table (the_date) VALUES(NOW())";)
```

The problem is, for some reason, NOW() as I have it here is recording into the database a 12-hour clock. (1:03 PM records as 01:03:00, instead of 13:03:00.)

What can I do to specify to NOW() that it be formatted as 24-hour?

I have read a lot about formatting things. Unfortunately, as has happened many times in the past, there are small, almost imperceptible formatting issues that can make things not work out quite right.

I am trying to make sure I do not do a long time of trial-and-error to make sure I get the formatting correct.

I THINK that the line that says "`NOW()`" should be replaced with "`DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), %Y-%m-%d %T)`", but I am looking for independent confirmation that does not have me leading the witness, and someone saying "yeah that looks good enough."

Right now, entries in the database look like this:

```
2012-06-27 01:03:36
```

Which would be perfect, were it not that the time should read 13 instead of 01, like so:

```
2012-06-27 13:03:36
```

I know that "NOW()" is working, it just needs to be 24 hour format, which it is SUPPOSED to be by default.  For some reason this is not happening, and I'd just like to know what specific alphanumeric sequence to put in the stead of "NOW()" to record as a 24-hour format.

Comment: What is your time zone? Is it possible that it's just inserting everything 12 hours off? (What do you see in the morning?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the [documentation for `NOW()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now), I suspect that *either* your system is configured very strangely somehow, or you're in a time zone which is currently 12 hours "out" from UTC. (Or your server is *configured* to just use UTC, so it's giving the UTC time but you were expecting local time.) There's no indication from the documentation that the format returned by `NOW()` is affected by any cultural settings, for example.

I would suggest that in general, storing the result of [`UTC_TIMESTAMP()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_utc-timestamp) would be a better approach anyway - but of course you'll still want to make sure you end up with a sensible format.

What do you see in the morning, and do you see the same effect if you just use

```
SELECT NOW(), UTC_TIMESTAMP()
```

from an interactive query window? Likewise, do you have any other servers you could try the same query against? Which version of MySQL are you running?

Comment: I posted an answer, the tl;dr version is "Me=derp."

Answer (score 1):

NOW() should never return a 12-hour clock. It might be that your time zone setting is wrong.
Try to run select @@time_zone and see what the result is (Default should be SYSTEM). Your system clock may be in UTC. You can set time zones for MySQL according to the documentation here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman//5.5/en/time-zone-support.html

Answer (score 0):

Wrap NOW() in the [DATE_FORMAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function..

Comment: Can you give an example?  I am fearful because I thought "NOW()" was 24-hour by default, but instead I am getting stuff like this:
2012-06-27 01:03:36 (this is for an entry made at 1:00 PM).

Comment: I THINK that the line that says "NOW()" should be replaced with "DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), %Y-%m-%d %T)", but I am not sure.  Is this what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

Soooo, here's what happened:

The clients like to have poorly-formatted dates and times for their own eyes.  That's fine.

What is NOT fine is that someone, somewhere, in one little like of code that helps with displaying stuff all wrong for them, managed to be a part of how it is sometimes recorded.  The difference was "h" vs. "H", and that's why it was wrongly storing the time as 12 hour instead of 24 hour.

NOW() is definitely a 24-hour record by default, but the spaghetti code with which I work had changed it, in some circumstances, to record instead as 12-hour.

tl;dr---Oops, I didn't notice "h" should have been "H" somewhere, and this was a stupid question.   I'd like to petition my idiotic question be deleted.